# Setup local network on Mac and share it via WiFi, but with no internet connection

Tags: network, wifi

I woat to use my iPhone as remote control for VLC. I use http://hobbyistsoftware.com/VLC-more and it is working fine when I am connected to my AirPort network.

I will use my MacBook at a place where there is no AirPort connection (even currently is not available) for playing videos.

Is it possible and if so how do I run my mac as default gateway and access point but just for local network so that I can connect my iPhone to it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have WiFi turned on then you have a pizza slice icon at the right of the menu bar. If it isn't there then open `Network` in `System Preferences` to make sure WiFi is on and you have `Show Wi-Fi status in menu bar` selected.

Select `Create Network...` which will open up a dialog where you can specify a network name and security. I usually change security to `40-bit WEP` just so the link is secure.

You can now connect to this network from your iPhone in the same way as any other WiFi net.

Comment: To be noted that WEP-40 and WEP-104 are easily broken, deprecated and superseded by WPA/WPA2. Nobody should use WEP anymore, if possible.

Comment: @Jawa I will be using this in the middle of wilderness. there is no electricity for one km around it. So in my case I do not need to worry about security. Also this "Create Network.." is only giving WEP, WPA2 is not available.

Comment: How do you connect to this network from a non-mac computer?